# How to add callback to gstatic loader.js google charts library?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-loader

As mentioned in http://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code , it is advised to upgrade from old `jsapi` to new `gstatic...loader.js` for `google charts`.

Problem: Currently I'm having callback that is executed after loading of the js file completed:
http://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=oldCallback

But with the new library, this callback is never executed:

http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js?callback=newCallback

Why?

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rLo9vdqm/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listed under the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#limitations) for the *new* `loader.js`...

> 2. You can't `autoload` the library.

which I take as --> you can't include anything on the url...

you *can* include it with the `load` statement however...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: newCallback,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Well but this callback is executed when the `corechart` module was loaded. I need a callback when the  `loader.js` javascript library was loaded, as only the the `google.charts` variable is available at all, and I have to delay this call until then.